# SVD on TFIDF Matrix returns an odd shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, svd

The overarching problem:
I thought that running `fit_transform` on the model `TruncatedSVD` on `SparseVectors` from `TfidfVectorizer` would yield components with dimension (n_samples, n_components), as noted [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) (jump down to the `fit_transform` section).

However, I am getting back a matrix of shape (n_components, n_words).

Here is a trivial example to recreate the problem:

```
def build_tfidf_model(corpus):
    transformer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word')
    matrix = transformer.fit_transform(corpus)
    return matrix

def svd_tfidf_matrix(matrix):
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=3)
    svd.fit_transform(matrix)
    return svd.components_


corpus = ['sentence one', 'sentence two', 'another one', 'another sentence', 'two sentence', 'one sentence']
tfidf_model = build_tfidf_model(corpus)
reduced_vectors = svd_tfidf_matrix(matrix=tfidf_model)
```

So, `tfidf_model.shape` yields `(6, 4)`. This makes sense to me. I have a corpus of six documents, which contain a total of 4 distinct words.

However, `reduced_vectors.shape` yields `(3,4)`. I was expecting it to be of shape `(6,3)`.

I must be misunderstanding what calling `fit_transform` is supposed to return. What can I call for `SVD` to get it to return a matrix where the rows are the documents and the columns are the features in the reduced space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input represented in the transform space, then fit_transform will return that object. Currently youre calling it without assigning the result to a variable. The model.components_ attributes merely describe how you can transform the tfidf vector space to the svd space.

```
def svd_tfidf_matrix(matrix):
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=3)
    return svd.fit_transform(matrix)
```